# we find all contract of a user and all jobs of contract of that particular user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models one is **User** and another is **Contract**.
These are my models

```
  class User < ApplicationRecord
     has_many :user_jobs ,dependent: :destroy
     has_many :contracts ,through: :user_jobs
  end

  class Contract < ApplicationRecord
     has_many :user_jobs ,dependent: :destroy
     has_many :users ,through: :user_jobs       
  end
  class UserJob < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :contract
  end
```

we have to find all unique contracts of a user

Comment: show your user_jobs model AND what have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you already tried to achieve it? Can we see your code to fix it? Otherwise you ask us to do it instead of you.

Comment: `Contract.includes(user_jobs: :user).where(user_jobs: {user_id: user_id}).uniq` - does this work for you ?

Comment: @Priyadarshani mini : I added the above as a comment as I was not completely sure what you need. If this is what exactly worked for you, then you should reply back to the comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want only user's jobs then this will be perfect :

```
Contract.joins([:user_jobs=> [:user]]).where("users.id = ?",user_id).distinct
```

or directly

```
Contract.joins(:user_jobs).where("user_jobs.user_id = ?",user_id).distinct
```

Comment: Hey, many congratulations for your accepted answer after multiple edits!! Now, your answer exactly looks like my old answer.

Answer (score 2):

To find all unique `contracts` of a `user`, you can make a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` using `includes` which would also help you to eager load the association:

```
Contract.includes(user_jobs: :user).where(user_jobs: {user_id: user_id}).uniq
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a join involving several tables. (contracts, user_jobs & users).

```
# user_id = 1
Contract.includes(:users).where(users: {id: user_id}).distinct
```

But I think is better to make a user query to avoid the 3 table join as follows

```
# user = User.find(1)
user.contracts.distinct
```

Hope it helps